# ADF test stationary at 10% critical value

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller, breusch-pagan, critical-value

I was wondering when you use ADF method for unit root testing, if variables are stationary at 10% level, p-value just over .05. How can one be more confident that it is sationary, could you for example use a test for autocorrelation in residuals of the adf equation to make sure error terrm is white noise? exp. breusch Pagan test?

Appreciate every answer :)